# Adding a progress bar on SMSlib sendmessage using Swing (netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, smslib

Hi I am new to java and this would be my first time using the progressbar. I tried using google for example but have no idea no how to use it on SMSlib sendmessage java class.

```
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import org.smslib.AGateway;
import org.smslib.IOutboundMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.Library;
import org.smslib.OutboundMessage;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway;

public class SendMessage
{
    public void doIt(String recipient, String message) throws Exception
    {
        OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
        System.out.println("Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
        System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
        System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
        SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com1", "COM54", 115200, "Wavecom", "m1306b");
        gateway.setInbound(true);
        gateway.setOutbound(true);
        gateway.setSimPin("");
        gateway.setSmscNumber("+639170000130");
        Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
        Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
        Service.getInstance().startService();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Modem Information:");
        System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
        System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
        System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
        System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
        System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
        System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
        System.out.println();
        // Send a message synchronously.
        OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(recipient,message);
        Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
        System.out.println(msg);

        Service.getInstance().stopService();
    }

    public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification
    {
        public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage msg)
        {
            System.out.println("Outbound handler called from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }


}
```

BTW im using netbeans as my IDE.

Jframe code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author K377Y
 */


public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainFrame
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        recipientField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        messageField = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        sendButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 300));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 300));
        setResizable(false);

        recipientField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                recipientFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        messageField.setColumns(20);
        messageField.setLineWrap(true);
        messageField.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(messageField);

        jLabel1.setText("Recipient");

        jLabel2.setText("Text Message");

        sendButton.setText("Send");
        sendButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                sendButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(sendButton)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(recipientField)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                    .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 357, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(recipientField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addComponent(sendButton)
                .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void recipientFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void sendButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      SendMessage sms = new SendMessage();

     try
        {
            sms.doIt(recipientField.getText(),messageField.getText());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea messageField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField recipientField;
    private javax.swing.JButton sendButton;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: The most likely solution would be to use a SwingWorker to actually performing the sending action. Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a complete example with a `SwingWorker` with a progressBar. [Swing Worker Example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/).

Basically you use a `Swingworker` to run heavy task in a background thread to don't block your gui.

A simple example:

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground() throws Exception {
       //here you make heavy task this is running in another thread not in EDT
       // call your smslib
       setProgress(0);
       // do some another operation
       setProgress(43);
       // another operation
       setProgress(89);
       .
       .
    }
}
```

And in your client code where you have the progressBar:

```
SwingWorker myWorker = new Worker();
myWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent event) {
    switch (event.getPropertyName()) {
    case "progress":
      myProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
      myProgressBar.setValue((Integer) event.getNewValue());
      break;
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: @MarcLevinsonSuarez Read the example in the link, it's a very good article in my opinion