# How to fix java.io.IOException: write error, when use smsLib Java

Tags: java, ioexception, gsm, smslib

I am trying to send message from java to GSM Modem like wavecom,
and I found this post : [Adding a progress bar on SMSlib sendmessage using Swing (netbeans)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414454/adding-a-progress-bar-on-smslib-sendmessage-using-swing-netbeans)

When I run `sendMessage` class I am getting this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: write error
    at com.sun.comm.Win32SerialPort.write(Win32SerialPort.java:677)
    at com.sun.comm.Win32SerialOutputStream.write(Win32SerialOutputStream.java:38)
    at org.smslib.modem.SerialModemDriver.write(SerialModemDriver.java:166)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.write(AModemDriver.java:302)
    at org.smslib.modem.athandler.ATHandler_Wavecom.done(ATHandler_Wavecom.java:52)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.stopGateway(ModemGateway.java:201)
    at org.smslib.Service.stopService(Service.java:355)
    at org.smslib.Service.startService(Service.java:234)
    at org.smslib.Service.startService(Service.java:196)
    at consoledmt.SendMessage.sendMessage(SendMessage.java:42)
    at consoledmt.SendMessage.main(SendMessage.java:86)
```

Here is the code sir:

```
import java.net.URL;

import org.smslib.AGateway;
import org.smslib.IOutboundMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.Library;
import org.smslib.OutboundMessage;
import org.smslib.OutboundWapSIMessage;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway;

public class SendMessage {

    public void sendMessage() throws Exception {
        OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
        System.out.println("Sample of Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
        System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
        System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
        SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com16", "COM16", 115200, "Wavecom", "M1206B");
        gateway.setInbound(false);
        gateway.setOutbound(true);
        // gateway.setSimPin("");
        Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(
                outboundNotification);
        Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
        Service.getInstance().startService();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Modem Information:");
        System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
        System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
        System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
        System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
        System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel()+ " dBm");
        System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel()+ "%");

        // Send a message synchronously.
        OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("+6283806120618",
                "SMS test: sample message from StackOverflow");

        Service srvice = Service.getInstance();
        // Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
        System.out.println(msg);
        // Or, send out a WAP SI message.
        OutboundWapSIMessage wapMsg = new OutboundWapSIMessage("+6283806120618",
                new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/"),
                "WAP test: sample message from StackOverflow!");
        // gateway.setFrom("chandpriyankara");
        // wapMsg.setFrom("chandpriyankara");
        srvice.queueMessage(wapMsg);

        Service.getInstance().stopService();
    }

    /**
     * Outbound Message informations handler
     * 
     * @author chandpriyankara
     * 
     */
    public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification {
        public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage msg) {
            System.out.println("Outbound handler called from Gateway: "+ gateway.getGatewayId());
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SendMessage app = new SendMessage();
        try {
          app.sendMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a piece of code causing this error, not only stacktrace

Comment: In your question. Not as an answer. It isn't an answer.

Comment: i've found the reason @RetteMich, thet couse my sim card is expired, that's my fault